# Django with IIS server restart unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, iis, restart

I currently developing a Django Project which use IIS as web server.
When I make some of the ajax request, the server will restart by itself with unknown reason.
I have made some log and pretty sure the restart occurs just before Django run the corresponding function in views.py, but I don't know if the restart occurs before or after the server receive request.

Does anyone have some idea on this issue?

Comment: Addition: I am sure there is no error in both javascript and django

Comment: Check the advanced properties of application pool to make sure it is set to log events. Then you can get the log from windows event view. It will record restart time. Check the log module of IIS to get the time of request. Then you can know if the restart occurs before or after the server receive request.